# Is there a way I can print a subset of my PCA?

Tags: r

I need to use the most principal components for my experiment and because my dataset is large and there is collinearity between the features, I decided to use PCA to reduce the features to the principal components. The total number of my PCA variables is 126. However, only PCA1, - PCA25 are significantly important for my experiment and I have tried `pc1 <- pc[,PC1:PC25]`and it does appear that the code is wrong because it gave me error. I need a away to subset PCA1 to PCA25 of the total PCA. Please can anyone help?

```
  pc <- prcomp(training[,-127], center = TRUE)
  > summary(pc)
  Importance of components:
                         PC1   PC2     PC3     PC4    PC5     PC6     PC7    PC8     PC9    PC10
  Standard deviation     5.562 3.908 3.28338 3.03513 2.4405 2.10462 1.98950 1.7913 1.58383 1.58122
  Proportion of Variance 0.241 0.119 0.08399 0.07177 0.0464 0.03451 0.03084 0.0250 0.01954 0.01948
  Cumulative Proportion  0.241 0.360 0.44402 0.51578 0.5622 0.59669 0.62753 0.6525 0.67207 0.69154
                         PC11    PC12    PC13    PC14    PC15    PC16    PC17    PC18    PC19
  Standard deviation     1.56896 1.53537 1.52657 1.50592 1.48985 1.43354 1.39342 1.37561 1.29827
  Proportion of Variance 0.01918 0.01836 0.01816 0.01767 0.01729 0.01601 0.01513 0.01474 0.01313
  Cumulative Proportion  0.71072 0.72909 0.74724 0.76491 0.78220 0.79821 0.81334 0.82808 0.84121
                         PC20    PC21   PC22    PC23    PC24    PC25    PC26    PC27    PC28
  Standard deviation     1.26082 1.20600 1.1160 1.09146 1.02691 1.00610 0.92149 0.91075 0.87977
  Proportion of Variance 0.01238 0.01133 0.0097 0.00928 0.00822 0.00789 0.00662 0.00646 0.00603
  Cumulative Proportion  0.85359 0.86492 0.8746 0.88391 0.89212 0.90001 0.90663 0.91309 0.91912
```

Comment: `pc$x[,1:25]` to get the coordinates of the rotated data. Consider using [Horn's parallel analysis](https://rdrr.io/cran/paran/man/paran.html) to get the number of PCs that should be kept if doing EDA, if using pca as preprocessor for supervised learning, the number of PCs retained should be treated as any other hyper parameter and optimized jointly with other hyper pars using some sort of resampling.

Comment: Thanks @missuse, it worked for me